# No Tuition Assistance Program benefit on offer letter

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, recruitment, human-resources, benefits

I got an offer letter today and what I want most is not on the offer letter - Tuition Assistance Benefit. I have accepted the offer before realising this (my bad). I am going to call the recruiter tomorrow to ask how that works but then I am wondering if it should have been on the offer letter or it is a discussion to have with HR after resumption.

I didn't discuss it at the interview but they wrote it on their website and part of the job requirement is someone going through the professional studies (CPA).

Also, I notice there is no paid sick days benefit. I am going to ask about this since I have a little girl but then wondering if it should be on the offer letter. Only the number of vacation days is on the offer letter.

Comment: Did you previously discuss tuition assistance with the firm? Was it a benefit you were expecting (and the company knew you were expecting)?

Comment: I didnt discuss it at the interview but they wrote it on their website and part of the job requirement is someone going through the professional studies (CPA)

Comment: Because i saw it on the reviews on indeed .com and honestly, it never came up. At the second interview, the director said they have a lot of training for staff and the current manager was pursuing the same certification when she joined the company, i somehow got distracted and forgot to ask. Now its not on the offer, waiting to hear back from the recruiter

Comment: What country are you writing from? This may change some of the insights provided.

Answer (score 10):

Many a times, companies do not list all the benefits as part of the offer letter, but as separate policy documents which they share separately (sometimes along with the offer letter, sometimes after you sign the offer letter but before you join, sometimes at the time of your joining).

Depending on the size of the company, there could be separate policies for health reimbursements, leaves due to sickness and other reasons, Tuition Assistance Benefit, insurance benefits, relocation policies and so on.

So, in your case, you should reach out with an email / phone call to your HR/recruiter contact and enquire about the details for these policies. If s/he is able to share the corresponding policy documents that would be good, but even otherwise, a written mail from them confirming these benefits should be enough for you to progress in good faith.

Also a caveat: Many tuition assistance programs require that you seek a manager/HR approval before you join/begin the course, so do get clarity on whether the benefit covers your ongoing educational engagements or not.

Comment: +1.  Especially for "reach out with an email / phone call." Like many workplace puzzles, they get easier to solve when you talk to people!

Comment: Definitely call and ask to receive a benefits package. I don't know how you can intelligently accept an offer without knowing the benefits including employee costs. I had an offer from a startup once and it was good that I asked for the benefits package because instead of the company providing health insurance, they offered money towards the employee buying their own health insurance. For a single-person the money was adequate but for someone with a family, that nice salary increase for changing jobs would have turned into a salary decrease after paying for health insurance.

Answer (score 1):

Often such a benefit may only become available once the candidate passes their probation period. It may also be subject to a certain period of continued employment during and after completion of studies done under such a benefit.

Your best course of action would be to inquire about such a benefit with your boss or HR department.  From there you should know where you stand and what your next step should be.

The reason PTO is listed, is probably because companies often give more PTO than is required by law, so it is put in writing for the benefit of the employee.  As for the sick days, this is usually a standard benefit in compliance with local labor laws, but it wouldn't hurt to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem unusual to me that tuition reimbursement isn't mentioned in an offer letter. At this point in my career, I've probably seen around a dozen offer letters (turned at least a couple down). Salary is always named. Vacation - if it is outside the normal allotment - will be listed in the letter. However, in my recollection, not a single offer letter listed details of all the benefits available. This includes tuition reimbursement (when available). At most, they referred to a standard set of benefits which would be in a separate document.

As mentioned by other answers, it never hurts to ask. If that seems awkward, you might check the company's web site first, where tuition reimbursement might be listed as a standard benefit.

Depending on the company, they might even be willing to pay for tuition if it isn't a defined benefit: I once took a class at the local community college that was meant as a stepping stone to my next job. It was in the broader field in which I worked, but not applicable to any work I was doing for that company. Because that employer hadn't mentioned tuition assistance as a benefit, it seemed unrelated to work, and the course was (relatively) inexpensive, I just paid for it myself. However, on the nights that class met there was no staying late for me. So my boss wondered why I wanted to leave so promptly those nights, since I often stayed at least a little late. When I told him why, he asked why I hadn't mentioned it before, because he would have gotten the company to pay for it, as it was close enough to job-related in his judgment.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I spoke with the recruiter and she confirmed they provide Tuition Assistance after completion of the six months probationary period. Also gave me a link to other benefits.